# NodeJs Can't decrypt result ecrypted in Java (AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding)

Tags: java, node.js, encryption

I'm working with a client and made some code to decrypt a value that their system encrypts.
They are using Java (which I'm not familiar with) and have used the following code example:
https://howtodoinjava.com/java/java-security/java-aes-encryption-example/

The following node.js code worked with my testing examples but returns an error when trying to decrypt theirs

```
const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-256-ecb", ENC_KEY, null);
decipher.setAutoPadding(true);
deciphered = decipher.update(encryptedValue, "base64", "utf8");
deciphered += decipher.final("utf8");
console.log(deciphered);
```

Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt

My research online hasn't returned any solution that worked so far.

Am I missing something in my code?

EDIT: After more research i found that crypto already does pkcs5padding by default and setting autoPadding to false resolved the bad decrypt however I now get some strange characters (�[�→>↔��I�O�v L�▼v���.,
��<G��♠V�/,J9�) and not the expected result

Comment: What is `ENC_KEY` in the NodeJS code (i.e. have you considered the key derivation via SHA-1)? Also, the Java code applies AES-128. The article fails to point out that ECB and SHA-1 as key derivation are insecure.

Comment: `ENC_KEY` is the key we defined. After researching I have changed to aes-128-ecb and hashed the `ENC_KEY` as such `var key = crypto.scryptSync(ENC_KEY, 'sha1', 16)` but still don't get a readable result.
EDIT: I've also learned that it is insecure however this is not to exchange sensitive information. It is just a way to avoid exploitation of our system.

Comment: If you want to decrypt the ciphertext generated by the Java code, then of course you have to apply the key derivation used in the Java code (and that is not *scrypt*), see here: https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/xKT.

Comment: That worked! I was starting to come to the conclusion that the key was the issue but I am not experienced with cryptography and Java enough to understand what I was missing.
If you write your comment as an answer I'll mark it as correct to save some time to whoever needs this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who encounters the same problem as me follow the solution @Topaco added in the comments:

> If you want to decrypt the ciphertext generated by the Java code, then of course you have to apply the key derivation used in the Java code (and that is not scrypt), see here: jdoodle.com/ia/xKT.

https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/xKT